# Updated version of delete button as control replacement for object in Fabricjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, fabricjs

I need to create a delete button on the objects I add to the canvas replacing the top right corner, or the 'tr' property of the controls. I have not found a solution to do this as previous versions cause the entire framework to stop functioning.

I have found solutions to my problem for previous FabricJS versions, which are now obsolete in Fabric 3.0.0. The link provided is the exact issue I have, I just need an update to the current version of the framework.
Required solution to update: [Add Delete button on element in Canvas Fabric JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35630508/add-delete-button-on-element-in-canvas-fabric-js)

Answer (score 2):

I have tried the same solution with version 3.0.0. It still work without much changes.
See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/swap123/xn8puhec/3/)

**HTML**

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.0.0/fabric.min.js"></script>

<div id="canvas-container" class="over">
    <div class="canvas-container" style="width: 800px; height: 600px; position: relative; -webkit-user-select: none;">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var HideControls = {
            'tl':true,
            'tr':false,
            'bl':true,
            'br':true,
            'ml':true,
            'mt':true,
            'mr':true,
            'mb':true,
            'mtr':true
        };
fabric.Image.fromURL('http://img.etimg.com/thumb/height-480,width-640,msid-65658383,imgsize-103718/google-chrome.jpg', function (img) {
    img.top = 60;
    img.left = 30;
    img.setControlsVisibility(HideControls);
    canvas.add(img);
});

canvas.renderAll();

function addDeleteBtn(x, y){
    $(".deleteBtn").remove(); 
    var btnLeft = x-10;
    var btnTop = y-10;
    var deleteBtn = '<img src="http://www.imcjms.com/assets/images/close-window.png" class="deleteBtn" style="position:absolute;top:'+btnTop+'px;left:'+btnLeft+'px;cursor:pointer;width:20px;height:20px;"/>';
    $(".canvas-container").append(deleteBtn);
}

canvas.on('object:selected',function(e){
        addDeleteBtn(e.target.oCoords.tr.x, e.target.oCoords.tr.y);
});

canvas.on('mouse:down',function(e){
    if(!canvas.getActiveObject())
    {
        $(".deleteBtn").remove(); 
    }
});

canvas.on('object:modified',function(e){
    addDeleteBtn(e.target.oCoords.tr.x, e.target.oCoords.tr.y);
});

canvas.on('object:scaling',function(e){
    $(".deleteBtn").remove(); 
});
canvas.on('object:moving',function(e){
    $(".deleteBtn").remove(); 
});
canvas.on('object:rotating',function(e){
    $(".deleteBtn").remove(); 
});
$(document).on('click',".deleteBtn",function(){
    if(canvas.getActiveObject())
    {
        canvas.remove(canvas.getActiveObject());
        $(".deleteBtn").remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I am sorry that I forgot to specify that I want it on the HTML5 canvas rather than a DOM element, as that is not as reliable.

Comment: I think [this](https://pixolith.github.io/fabricjs-customise-controls-extension/example/index.html) plugin might help you.

Comment: I have tried using this plugin already, however it is outdated and does not work for this version of fabric js.